# Regular expression works in pythex.org & rubular.com, doesn't work in pyrex.com & in the code. Why?

Tags: python, regex, validation

I have this line

```
line = learnAction&subscriberId=604c21a0-0dc5-47da-9a1e-bfb53fa0fab8&
```

and this regex to find  **subscriberId=604c21a0-0dc5-47da-9a1e-bfb53fa0fab8**

```
subscriberId=[\d\w-]*
```

it finds this string in pythex.org & rubular.com and not in pyrex.com and in my code

```
(r"""subscriberId=[\d\w-]*""",line)
```

Who's to blame? and what to do?
Thanks!

Comment: pyrex.com looks like a commercial website.

Comment: Use `re.search`, not `re.match`. Besides, `[\w\d]` = `\w`. `[\w-]` is enough.

Comment: and rubular.com is for **Ruby** regexes. Nevertheless the `r` prefix is **not** regex, it means **r**aw string.

Comment: Isn't pyrex a brand of cookware?

Answer (score 1):

try re

```
import re
line = 'learnAction&subscriberId=604c21a0-0dc5-47da-9a1e-bfb53fa0fab8&'
if re.search("subscriberId=[\d\w-]*", line):
    print 'match'
```

Comment: Try doesn't explain the difference in your answer or why it should work. Please explain every answer!